# Internet Explorer 7, 8 & 9: canvas support (Mootools)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, mootools

I have written this Mootools example of a simple tool using canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/beingalex/MZTbW/11/

It simply creates a line from one clicked location to the other.

I have two questions really, both relating to Internet Explorer's support of the `canvas` tag.

1. I was under the impression that IE9 supported `canvas` but from the demonstration above I conclude I was wrong. Or am I? I have implemented it incorrectly?
2. I know that IE 7 & 8 do not support `canvas` so I am looking for advice on how to go about doing what I have done in the demonstration above for these browsers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know about IE9 it should work, but for older versions of IE, excanvas ( http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/ ) brings canvas support to them

Comment: Thanks. I will use excanvas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 perfectly supports canvas.

If your page doesn't work fine it's usually because your header isn't right. Use this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

For IE7 and IE8 you'll need this : http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true